# Preferred way to private messages modeling in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I plan to implement a private message system between members. I'm wondering what are the preferred approaches to this.

Requirements are

1. I should be able to retrieve them easily as something like this

   ```
   @user.conversations               #Should return User objects that I sent or received messages from (but not me)
   @user.conversations.messages      #Messages from all or specific user objects.
   @user.conversations.messages.unread      #Unread messages
   ```
2. When calling @user.conversations should retrieve only the people that sent me messages or people I send messages to. current_user should be excluded.
3. If i'm sender_id=5 and send to_id=10 then, the other person would reply as sender=10 to_id=5. This should be considered and understood as the same conversation object.

---

Regarding last point. I'm not sure what's the preferred approach to modeling.

It's preferred to use one Conversation model to handle all messages such as

```
    attr_accessible :user_id, :friend_id, :message, :read
    belongs_to :user
```

Or it's preferred to create a Conversation model to handle association and a Message model for messages.

I would like to see sample cases of how to implement this relationship and if there's additional method to implement.

I'm a bit lost here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A much simpler model is to capture each Message:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :from_user,  :class_name => 'User' # from_user_id field fk Users
  belongs_to :to_user,    :class_name => 'User' # to_user_id field fk Users
  belongs_to :thread, :class_name => 'Message'  # Reference to parent message
  has_many :replies,  :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'thread_id'

  named_scope :in_reply_to, lambda { |message| :conditions => {:thread => message}, :order => 'created_at' }
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages_received,  :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key=> 'to_user_id'
  has_many :messages_sent,      :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key=> 'from_user_id'
end
```

If you need to capture the message threads, any Message that's a reply can store a reference to the initial message starting the Conversation (aka Thread).  For example:

```
first_msg   = Message.new(:to_user => bob, :from_user => sally, :body => 'Hello!')
sally_reply = first_msg.replies.build(:to_user => bob, :from_user => sally, :body => 'hi back')
bob_reply   = first_msg.replies.build(:to_user => sally, :from_user => bob, :body => 'later')
```

Comment: @Winfield How can I get the root document using the in_reply_to ? I want to have something like twitter DM

Comment: Root messages will have a null in_reply_to value.

Comment: @Winfield Thanks, I solved it by adding before_create filter, to add thread_id as message_id incase there is was no thread_id provided. This returns all documents including the main one.

Answer (score 4):

[acts_as_messageable](https://github.com/psergi/acts_as_messageable) is a bit long in the tooth, but should give you some ideas.

Comment: I would prefer this, as many act_as_* plugins/gems out there. And according to requirement which @Martin mentioned above it fits his needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using this DB model:

```
User id:integer ....

Message id:integer body:string

UserMessages id:integre sender_id:integer to_id:integer message_id
```

I guess you will need to provide :finder_sql in :has_many, something like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :conversations, :class_name => "UserMessage", :finder_sql =>
      'SELECT * ' +
      'FROM user_messages' +
      'WHERE sender_id = #{id} OR to_id = #{id} ' 

end
```

Comment: Also you can use <Model>.column_names["attr_accessible"].name for db column name you want and <Model>.table_name to avoid naming issues

Answer (score 1):

Were you, I would have went with IMAP instead of using the DB for such modeling.

Check [this](http://beilabs.com/posts/700502155-messing-around-with-the-ruby-imap-and-mail-libraries) for more details.